# Problem sending response message from one client to another socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My problem is the following:
I have 2 apps that communicate through a socket server. App1 sends a message to app 2 through the message event. This works correctly because app 2 gets the message right, what I'm trying to do is send another reply message from app 2 to 1 to warn that the message arrived well. For this I have an event called estado_mensaje that is emitted within the message event and on the server when listening to this event it emits the mensaje_ok event, this is shown fine in the server console, but I can't get that message in app 1. this is my code:

**server node**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 4444;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

UserOnId=new Array();
IdsOnUser=new Array();
io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('datos_usuario', function(datos){
 id_socket=socket.id;
 usuario=datos.username;
 UserOnId[id_socket]=usuario;

 if(IdsOnUser[usuario]==null){
  IdsOnUser[usuario]=new Array();
 }
 IdsOnUser[usuario].push(id_socket);

console.log('------usuarios por id_socket------');
console.log(UserOnId);
console.log('------IDs socket por usuarios------');
console.log(IdsOnUser);
console.log('Cantidad de usuarios en lineas');
console.log(Object.keys(IdsOnUser).length);
 io.emit('nuevo_usuario', datos);

});


socket.on('message', function(datos){

  if(datos.user_to!=''){
      destinatario=datos.user_to;
      if(IdsOnUser[destinatario]){
          id_onlines=IdsOnUser[destinatario];
          for (var i=0;i<id_onlines.length;i++){
              io.to(id_onlines[i]).emit('message', datos);
          }
          io.to(socket.id).emit('message', datos);
      }

  }else {
      io.emit('message', datos);
  }
    console.log(datos.contenido);


});


socket.on('estado_mensaje ', function(datos){

    console.log(datos);
    io.emit('ok_mensaje', datos);

});
```

**App1**

```
var socket = io();
$(function () {


    $('form').submit(function(){
        var id_usuario_logueado=$('#id_username').val();
        var usuario_logueado=$('#username').val();
        var id_user_to=$('#id_receptor').val();
        var user_to=$('#receptor').val();
        datos={id_user_from:id_usuario_logueado,user_from:usuario_logueado,id_user_to:id_user_to,user_to:user_to,contenido:$('#m').val()};
        /*Envia un mensaje a traves del canal message*/
        socket.emit('message', datos);
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });

    socket.on('message', function(datos){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(datos.user_from+':'+datos.contenido));
        console.log(datos);
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

    });

    socket.on('nuevo_usuario', function(datos){

        console.log('Usuario logueado: '+datos.username);
        var usuario_logueado=$('#usuario_logueado').val(datos.username);

    });

    socket.on('ok_mensaje ', function(datos){

        alert('llega la respuesta');
        console.log(datos);


    });

});
function loguear(){
    var username=$('#username').val();
    socket.emit('datos_usuario', {username:username});
}
```

**App2**

```
socket.on('message', function(datos){
    $.ajax({
    url: "index.php?route=administracion/chat/send_message&token=" + token,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    async:true,
    data:{ id_user_from : id_user_from,id_user_to: id_user_to },
    success: function (json) {
      /*Here is how I emit the response to the other app*/
       socket.emit('estado_mensaje ', {status:'sucess'});
       console.log('guarda bien');
    },
    error: function(json){
        console.log('guarda mal');
        socket.emit('estado_mensaje ', {status:'error'});

    }
});
});
```

Comment: If app1 is a page in a browser, are you 100% sure that app1 is still on the same page it was before?  Remember, all socket.io state is wiped out (and has to be re-established) when the page reloads.  If you were sending from app1 from a form submission that was causing the page to reload, you could be losing your listeners.  I would ask you to show us much more code context from app1 so we can see exactly how the different parts of run and triggered.

Comment: Could you show us where you `require` your socket.io linrary?

Comment: I updated and put all the code above. None of the 2 apps reload the page. App 1 is a simple form where the message is put and the user to whom the message will be sent, when subtmitting the page does not reload. It arrives well and app2 sends an event with the confirmation message, which is displayed well in the node server console but is not shown in the app1 console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slight mismatch in message names.

Late in your sequence, your server does this:

```
io.emit('ok_mensaje', datos);
```

But app1 is doing this:

```
socket.on('ok_mensaje ', function(datos){ ...});
```

**See how there's a space at the end of one message name, but not the other.  They don't match.**  This whole concept of putting spaces at the end of your messages named seems (to me) like a horrible convention.  If you want to differentiate messages, use a leading underscore or a prefix like your `ok_` or something that is extremely visible, not something that is so subtle as a trailing space.

FYI, here's the sequence of things that happen which is sometimes how you have to debug these, to unwrap the actual sequence into a sequential set of code you can more easily follow.  That's how I found the problem above:

```
// client (app1)
socket.emit('message', datos);

// server
socket.on('message', function(datos){

    // ...
    for (var i=0;i<id_onlines.length;i++){
        io.to(id_onlines[i]).emit('message', datos);
    }   
    io.to(socket.id).emit('message', datos);

});

// client (app2)
socket.on('message', function(datos){
    socket.emit('estado_mensaje ', {status:'sucess'});
});

// server
socket.on('estado_mensaje ', function(datos){
    console.log(datos);
    io.emit('ok_mensaje', datos);
});

// *** Everything works up to here ***
// *** the next part does not work ***

// client (app1)

socket.on('ok_mensaje ', function(datos){
    alert('llega la respuesta');
    console.log(datos);
});
```